# Redirecting disables scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I'm developing an react app, and I'm redirecting page from a modal. The redirects but it is displaying the wanted page and dosen't enables to scroll it. 
(After refreshing, scroll is enabled)

I have tried using this.props.history.push, and also window.location.replace/href, and both behaved the same way.

```
            <ReactModal
                closeOnOverlayClick
                shouldCloseOnEsc
                showCloseIcon
                open={this.state.loginModal}
                center
                onClose={this.openLoginModal}>
                <Login redirTo={this.state.redirTo} history={this.props.history} postLoginCb={this.postLogin} ></Login>
            </ReactModal>
```

This code is in a bigger component.The redirect is inside Login (I sent history cause its not having its own as a modal).

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to trigger `this.closeLoginModal`, or some other method which will remove overflow: hidden from `<body>`

Comment: Not working. Even when I'm setting overflow:scroll to <body> in the inspector, the browser shows it as there is nothing to show by scrolling.